# Why is the name of the minimized app not shown while using the Numix theme in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, themes

I loved the Numix theme and I installed it in Lubuntu 13.10 and now, when I apply it, it does not show the name of the minimized app.

[image: name missing for minimized app]

It does not even has option to edit!

[image: no option to edit]

Answer (score 2):

LXDE panel is not currently supported. I have no knowledge about LXDE, so I would love if someone steps up and adds support for LXDE panel.

About no option to edit, I don't know about that either. Numix uses standard color definitions, so I have no clue why there is no edit option. Again, i'll love when someone helps me with it.

Comment: satya164, please see my answer below. I don't think you need to add any special support for LXDE. Your theme works just as well in Lubuntu as it does in Xubuntu!

Answer (score 2):

To see the name of the minimized app ...

- Right-click in any free space on your lxpanel. You should see this:

[image: lxpanel 1]

- Click on `Panel Settings` and then on the `Panel Applets` tab. You should see this:

[image: Panel applets]

Look for `Task Bar (Window List)`. Single-click on that and then click on `Edit` on the right-hand side. You should see this:

[image: Task Bar Edit]

See the `Icons only`. If you only want icons, *tick* that. If you want both icon and name (as your question indicates), keep the box *unticked*.

[image: Icons and names]

---

This is to answer the part about "no option to edit the color" in your lower image (the Customize Look and Appearance).

In this image you have the "Widget" tab active. That only allows you to select a theme from the list and you have selected "Numix".

Now click on the next tab which is "Color". You should see something like this:

[image: Color tab]

Make sure you tick "Use customized color scheme". Once you tick that you can then choose to modify various aspects of the theme you already chose in the "Widget" tab.

I changed the "Selected items:" color from orange, the default, to light green by clicking on the color wheel that opens up when you click in the box next to "Selected items:".

By the way, you can (carefully) explore the other tabs as well!

Comment: great!! You Helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on panel, **"add/remove panel items"**, select **"task bar (window list)"**, click **edit**, activate **"flat buttons"**, This should help for the **color** integration to **numix**.

The **text color** then also needs to be altered in order get higher contrast.
right click on panel and select **"panel settings"**, then **"appearance"** there you can choose a **custom color** for the text, for example: #FFFFFF. 
for **background color "system theme"** should be selected

Comment: Could you be more verbose?

Comment: This solves exactly my problem.